# Does express provides different req and res objects for each individual request?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using `Express Router` as shown below

```
router.post('/do', function(req, res, next) {
   // some sample code
   var questions = new Questions();
   questions.display(req, res); 
});
```

The `display` function takes care of calling `res.send`.

In above snippet I am creating instance of `Questions` and passing `req, res` objects to it.

Now from my `sample.js` file I am firing almost 5 ajax requests to this same route and only one request is succeeding and after that I am getting error

```
Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

So I am not sure why I am getting this error!.

Can anybody help ?

**UPDATE**

Code in display function

```
Questions.prototype.display = function(req, res) {

  // Check if type of question exists
  if (req.body.questionType) {
    res.send({message: 'No Type found in request body!'});
  } else {
    // logic for getting questions from DB based on question type
    return res.send(questions);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your function takes request while you pass req to your question. Assuming the error you print is from your express server it would be useful to see additional code from your question and question.display(). I'm running a server using express router in the same manner, and I run 10 requests to the same endpoint when building certain pages, and it works just fine, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Robin: updated with code.

Comment: I am not sure you still pass req, res into Questions ? var questions = new Questions();
   questions.display(req, res);

Comment: @RistoNovik: updated questions. I am passing `req` and `res` into display method.

Comment: Well there is some code missing, there is some way you send already the response. Also remove the next from post handler function are you using some other middlewares also ?

Comment: Before you run express server could you add env variable for debugging and post the results back here ```DEBUG=express:* node server.js```

Answer (score 0):

change request to req:

```
router.post('/do', function(req, res, next) {
// some sample code
var questions = new Questions(req, res);
questions.display();
```

});

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

Comment: My Bad I was trying different approach. at that time it remained `request` but now updated again.

Comment: add return before res.send({message: 'No Type found in request body!'})
if (req.body.questionType) {
    return res.send({message: 'No Type found in request body!'});
  } else {
    // logic for getting questions from DB based on question type
    return res.send(questions);
  }